# ListPointPlot3D plotting 4 dimensions

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a data set with four columns, i.e. dimensions, all are numerical. The last attribute is either 0 or 1. So I want to plot the data in the following way: the first three entries are the coordinates and the determines the color (0:Red, 1: Green). I can plot this using `Graphics3D` like:

Example data:

```
list = {{1, 29., 2, 1}, {1, 0.9167, 1, 1}, {1, 2., 2, 0}, {1, 30., 1,0}, {1, 25., 2, 0}}
```

then:

```
ClearAll[plotPoint];
plotPoint[list_List] := Module[{c, a, g, s},
  {c, a, g, s} = list;
  If[s == 1,
   Graphics3D[{PointSize[Small], Green, Point[{c, a, g}]}],
   Graphics3D[{PointSize[Small], Red, Point[{c, a, g}]}]
   ]
  ]
```

then

```
Show[plotPoint /@ list]
```

delivers an output. What I now tried to achieve is to do this job with `ListPointPlot3D` to get axes and so on. But here I can only deliver a `ColorFunction` which takes three arguments (the coordinates) and I could not manage to get my fourth attribute (last components in data set) in there to get the coloring.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list2 = Style[{#, #2, #3}, #4 /. {0 -> Red, 1 -> Green}] & @@@ list; 
ListPointPlot3D[list2, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ListPointPlot3D[List /@ list[[All, ;; 3]], 
 PlotStyle -> (list[[All, 4]] /. {0 -> Red, 1 -> Green}), 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thanks a lot. O.K. when you know it -  it is simple, but if not.... One of the solutions where I ask myself why I haven't seen it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
Graphics3D[
 {PointSize[Large],
  Point[list[[All, ;; 3]], 
   VertexColors -> (Blend[{Red, Green}, #] & /@ list[[All, 4]])]
  },
 PlotRange -> Automatic,
 Options[ListPointPlot3D]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way to get the colors:

```
VertexColors -> IdentityMatrix[3][[1 + list[[All, 4]]]]
```

Comment: Thank you, cool application for `Blend`, too.